# Filter search from json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am building a onine bus booking web application like `redbus.in` in which i want to implement the filter search feature like the way it is implemented in redbus.

Here is the workflow

1.There are 4 dropdown boxes present with  values `droppint point`, `boardingpoint`, `bustype`,`opeartor name`

2.when user select one `dropping point` from the dropdown the result will shows only with list of buses with that dropping point ,if he select `dropping point` and `boarding point` then it will show the list of buses that contains only two of this and so on.

Ie whatever the user select from these 4 dropdown menu the result (list of buses ) will contains only with these values.

But i don't know how to implement it especially the filtering .

Here is the sample json for one bus

```
{
      "droppingPoints": [
  {
          "time": "09:45 PM",
          "location": "Kachiguda",
          "id": "1283518"
        },
        {
          "time": "09:55 PM",
          "location": "Narayanaguda",
          "id": "1283519"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:05 PM",
          "location": "Lakdi ka pool",
          "id": "1283520"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:15 PM",
          "location": "Punjagutta",
          "id": "1283521"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:25 PM",
          "location": "Srinivasa Colony",
          "id": "1283522"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:25 PM",
          "location": "SR Nagar",
          "id": "1283523"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:25 PM",
          "location": "Ameerpet",
          "id": "1283524"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:30 PM",
          "location": "Erragadda",
          "id": "1283525"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:35 PM",
          "location": "Bharat Nagar",
          "id": "1283526"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:40 PM",
          "location": "VIVEKANANDA NAGAR",
          "id": "1283527"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:40 PM",
          "location": "Kukatpally",
          "id": "1282840"
        },
          ],
      "availableSeats": 4,
      "partialCancellationAllowed": false,
      "arrivalTime": "07:00 AM",
      "boardingPoints": [

        {
          "time": "10:45 PM",
          "location": "K P H B",
          "id": "1282841"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:55 PM",
          "location": "Hydernagar",
          "id": "1283073"
        },
        {
          "time": "10:55 PM",
          "location": "Nizampet",
          "id": "1283074"
        },
        {
          "time": "11:00 PM",
          "location": "MiyaPur",
          "id": "1283072"
        },
        {
          "time": "11:05 PM",
          "location": "Miyapur Allwin X Road",
          "id": "1283422"
        },
        {
          "time": "11:15 PM",
          "location": "Kondapur",
          "id": "1283423"
        },
        {
          "time": "11:20 PM",
          "location": "Gachibowli",
          "id": "1283554"
        }
      ],
      "operatorName": "Morning Star Travels",
      "departureTime": "10:30 PM",
      "mTicketAllowed": true,
      "idProofRequired": true,
      "serviceId": "1572",
      "fare": "1090.0, 1190.0",
      "busType": "2+1 Sleeper Non A/C",
      "routeScheduleId": "84W157YI3YGZKH5B9K0TG4E40VI13",
      "commPCT": 7.6,
      "operatorId": 1572,
      "inventoryType": 2
    }
```

Currently i have this code in my hand

```
<script>
//when select item from dropping point
$('.drp').on('change',function(){
   search_buses();
});

//when select item from boarding point
$('.brp').on('change',function(){
   search_buses();
});

//when select item from butype
$('.bt').on('change',function(){
    search_buses();
});
//when select item from opearto name
$('.on').on('change',function(){
   search_buses();
});
//function for searching 
function search_buses(){
 //list of buses in json format.
  var bus_list;
}
</script>
```

i Want to implement filter functionality in `search_bus` function. but i don't know how to do that.

Comment: To start with, I suppose you should specify a parameter for `search_buses()` (or `search_bus()`?). Point 2: `bus_list` in `search_buses()` does refer to the json you show at the beginning of the question?

Comment: Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: also include where the JSON is coming from i suppose this is dynamic list. maybe ajax or soemthing like that :)

Comment: That Json is what you have on the serverside or in the client? How do you render it?

Comment: for filtering on the client side, you'd probably want to use a mvc framework like angular. these frameworks already cover basic functionality like filtering/sorting etc. ...

Comment: Yes, I vote for AngularJS, too: invest some time reading https://angularjs.org/ (if you feel brave choose Angular2, otherwise 1, it's a bit simpler).

Comment: @guradio JSON is from an api.

Comment: @Astaroth json is coming from an api server once its arrived  i am strong its in the `bus_list` variable

Comment: @MarcoS yes it refer to json i am refer in the question

Answer (score 0):

Filtering would be as easy as using the `filter` and the `some` javascrip methods:

```
function searchBusesByLocation(location) {
    filteredBuses = busesArray.filter(function (bus) {//this will create a new array with the filtered items
        return boardingPointLocationComparisson(bus, location);
    });

    return filteredBuses;
}

function boardingPointLocationComparisson(bus, location) {//i'm guessin you want to filter by location, you can do by date or adapt this function like you want
    return bus.boardingPoints.some(function (boardingPoint) {
        //the some function will iterate over the array and return true whenever the comparisson is true, false otherwise
        return boardingPoint.location === location;
    })
}
```

Then you call the `searchBusesByLocation` on the `change` event with the **location** the user has entered (you can adapt the code for the other cases).